# Novelty and Outlier Detection in Unsupervised Learning Style

Tags: svm, outliers, unsupervised-learning, gaussian-mixture-distribution, novelty-detection

Currently I am looking for some method to do novelty and outlier detection. I found some good example here using scikit-learn ([Link1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html)). However, it is based on supervised learning and I believe the idea behind is the 'One Class SVM'. Therefore, the method requires **the training data is not polluted by outliers**.

However, I have got some data that contaminated by outliers already. I can't separate a clean dataset for training purpose. I am wondering if there is an unsupervised learning based method to detect the outliers?

For example, my data can be fitted using Mixture of Gaussian model, but before applying GMM, I would like to get rid of the outliers.

Thanks very much. A.

Comment: Have a look at the ELKI toolkit, which has *tons* of unsupervised outlier detection algorithms.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Thanks for your reply. Could you name one or two famous unsupervised outlier detection algorithms please? I didn't use Java based ELKI before. Trying to develop or use something in Matlab.

Comment: DB-Outlier, kNN-Outlier and [Local Outlier Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_outlier_factor). Matlab won't scale well for these, because it doesn't support data indexing as far as I know.